# Updating python gspread list with empty string after index is removed

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am creating a bot in discord for organizing lists then updates the lists to google sheet via gspread. The lists updated fine, however, if someone removed themselves from the list, the corresponding cell does not get removed, unless a new person replaced them in the list. I think its because of how python deals with list where empty spaces are simply.. nothing therefore gspread just ignores it. Therefore, my question is how do I force gspread to update every cells with an empty string should the list doesn't contains one? Thanks.

```
# Some codes

import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'a json')
sh = gc.open_by_key("a key")


# My lists
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["d","e","f"]

list_of_lists = [list1, list2]

# Update list into sheet

sh.values_update(
                'Sheet1!A1:C2', # fixed cells
                params={'valueInputOption': 'RAW'},
                body={'values': list_of_lists}
            )
```

## output

[image: old]

```
# Update with new list

list1.remove("a")
list2.remove("d")

# Rerun list update
sh.values_update(
                'Sheet1!A1:C2', # fixed cells
                params={'valueInputOption': 'RAW'},
                body={'values': list_of_lists}
            )
```

## New output

[image: new]

## Wanted this output

[image: wanted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer, a dummy list including the empty values is used. And, the values are put using the method of `batch_update` in class gspread.models.Worksheet. In this case, one API call is used.

#### Modified script:

```
sh = gc.open_by_key("a key")
sheetName = 'Sheet1'  # Please set the sheet name.
worksheet = sh.worksheet(sheetName)

# My lists
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["d", "e", "f"]

list_of_lists = [list1, list2]
dummy = [[''] * len(e) for e in list_of_lists]

list1.remove("a")
list2.remove("d")

worksheet.batch_update([{
    'range': 'A1:C2',
    'values': dummy,
}, {
    'range': 'A1:C2',
    'values': list_of_lists,
}])
```

#### Reference:

- [batch_update(data, **kwargs)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch#gspread.models.Worksheet.batch_update)

Comment: Thank you! This works, however I have to change the length of the dummy to a fixed one instead of varying with the list because if for example the list is filled in google sheet by 5, and 3 players are removed, the last 2 columns will not get cleared because the length in the dummy now follow 3 instead of 5. Cheers!

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your advices. I could understand about it. From your advice, I try not to to use "How about this answer" and "How about this modification" in my answer in my future answers.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. It's not as important as the other items. It's just that adding "boilerplate" (exact duplicate text) to every post does not really add any useful meaning (at least in terms of technical writing).